# Как правильно разделить ответы полученные из foreach

Tags: php

Есть foreach который перебирает массив и выдает кнопки в телеграмм боте:

```
foreach($userButtons as $values) {
   
    $name = $values['name'];
    $tag = $values['tag'];

    if ($values['actual'] == true) {

    $kbd[][] = array("text" => "{$name}", "callback_data" => "!go_stage_4 {$tag}");
}
   }
$ResultMessage['reply_markup'] = json_encode(["inline_keyboard" => $kbd]);
```

**Как разделить полученные ответы из foreach, так что бы они были в два столбика как тут?:**

```
                $ResultMessage['reply_markup'] = json_encode(["inline_keyboard" => [
                [["text" => "Кнопка 1", "callback_data" => "!button1"], ["text" => "Кнопка2", "callback_data" => "!button2"]],
                [["text" => "Кнопка 3", "callback_data" => "/button3"], ["text" => "Кнопка4", "callback_data" => "/button4"]]
            ]]);
```

Comment: `array_chunk`  в помощь

Answer (score -2):

```
$kbd = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($userButtons as $values) {
    $name = $values['name'];
    $tag = $values['tag'];

    if ($values['actual'] == true) {
        $button = array("text" => "{$name}", "callback_data" => "!go_stage_4 {$tag}");
        $kbd[$i / 2][] = $button;
        $i++;
    }
}

$ResultMessage['reply_markup'] = json_encode(["inline_keyboard" => $kbd]);
```

ChatGTP смог дать ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов, созданных GPT и ChatGPT, недопустима?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-gpt-%d0%b8-chatgpt-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0)